# Есть ли в c# подобие библиотеки cstdlib чтобы использовать system();?

Tags: c#, cmd, время

Начал переносить свою программу на С# , столкнулся с такой проблемой

Основная задача в целом, это чтобы в программе на C# при нажатии на одну кнопку изменялось время на допустим 20.06.2008, а на другую все возвращалось восвояси

раньше делал все на с++ через system,но как это реализовать на c#?

Comment: приведите код, который у вас не получается, и то что вы уже сделали.

Comment: date 03/06/2018      // это раньше использовал в C++ через system ,а потом...

Comment: timeout /t 3 
net stop w32time 
net start w32time 

w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:time.nist.gov 
W32tm /resync /force

Comment: 1 строку я писал через system();чтобы поменять время на старое, 2 строка для того чтобы перезапустить службу времени и обновить время через интернет, соответственно было 2 кнопки, 1а меняла время, а 2 его обновляла на нормальное

Comment: нашел, как поменять время на другое, осталось понять, как обновить время на реальное

Comment: если кому будет интересно, вот : http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1232592.html